# geocodeAddressString search results differ for New York and NewYork

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, apple-maps, cllocationcoordinate2d

When trying to search with `geocodeAddressString` for `ATM Branch locator`, Newyork search gives FL state (place-marks returns Florida's Lat n Long). Whereas, New York gives NY state (place-marks returns NewYork's Lat n Long).
 we are using the following line,

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
    let usa = CLCircularRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 39.8282, longitude: -98.5795), radius: 4500000.0, identifier: "USA")
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(search, inRegion: usa, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in /* Error Handling */
```

Why? In google geocoding, it is working fine.

Comment: Can you post your code about the Geocoding request?

Comment: Hi ztan, pls find my edited code.